# gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: error while extracting legitimate url

Tags: python, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

I am extracting some legitimate  url features from 5000 records in dataset and later storing then appending all features into list and finally storing them seperately for performing operations.
no error while this code

```
#Function to extract features
def featureExtraction(url,label):

  features = []
  #Address bar based features (10)
  features.append(getDomain(url))
  features.append(havingIP(url))
  features.append(haveAtSign(url))
  features.append(getLength(url))
  features.append(getDepth(url))
  features.append(redirection(url))
  features.append(httpDomain(url))
  features.append(tinyURL(url))
  features.append(prefixSuffix(url))

  #Domain based features (4)
  dns = 0
  try:
    domain_name = whois.whois(urlparse(url).netloc)
  except:
    dns = 1

  features.append(dns)
  features.append(web_traffic(url))
  features.append(1 if dns == 1 else domainAge(domain_name))
  features.append(1 if dns == 1 else domainEnd(domain_name))

  # HTML & Javascript based features (4)
  try:
    response = requests.get(url)
  except:
    response = ""
  features.append(iframe(response))
  features.append(mouseOver(response))
  features.append(rightClick(response))
  features.append(forwarding(response))
  features.append(label)

  return features
```

but i am facing error while executing this function

```
#Extracting the feautres & storing them in a list
legi_features = []
label = 0

for i in range(0, 5000):
  url = legiurl['URLs'][i]
  legi_features.append(featureExtraction(url,label))
```

error is

```
    gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

  -> 1286 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  --> 945 self.sock = self._create_connection(
     -> 827 for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM)
     --> 962 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
   
     gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
        
 -> 1351         raise URLError(err)
   URLError:
```

Comment: It's not clear from you question where exactly the error occurs. Also, please provide an example of input data, which causes the error. You can obtain it by trying and catching this exception and printing out the problematic url.